# Using variables in arcpy.UpdateCursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, cursor

I've written a python script (ArcGIS 10.0) for importing point objects from Excel sheets to our ArcSDE database. This works fine, but I'd like to make this script a bit more custamizable by the user and therefore want to use a python list for updating my data. I've tried the following, but unfortunately the update cursor does not work together with a python list and I'm getting the error "Field item does not exist".

```
import os, arcpy

fc = r"C:\temp\temp.gdb\tempFC"
rowlist = [("NAME", "Testname"),("COMMENT", "Testcomment")]

print "Normal UpdateCursor"
fcCursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for row in fcCursor:
    row.NAME = "test 1"
    row.COMMENT = "test 1"
    fcCursor.updateRow(row)
del row
del fcCursor
print "Finished"

print "UpdateCursor with python list"
fcCursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for row in fcCursor:
    for item in rowlist:
        row.item[0] = item[1]
    fcCursor.updateRow(row)
del row
del fcCursor
print "Finished"
```

I've also tried

```
variable = "row.%s = %s" % (item[0], item[1])
variable
```

instead of

```
row.item[0] = item[1]
```

I'm not getting an error anymore, but nothing will be updated then.

Anyone another idea how to make this work?

Comment: May want to show where the error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the fields dynamically, which overall is a good strategy, but it does require a different syntax.

You are getting an error around `row.item[0]` because you are telling arcpy to update the field called `item` which doesn't exist, instead of the field that is named the value of `item[0]`.

Instead you should be using [`setValue`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000008r000000):

```
for row in fcCursor:
    for item in rowlist:
        row.setValue(item[0], item[1])
    fcCursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for! I already realized that arcpy treats my variable as field name but did not know the syntax to solve this problem. I've had a quick search for setValue and found out, that ESRI added this example to it's [10.1 Help page of the UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000064000000), but it's missing on the [10.0 pages](http://help.arcgis.com/de/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003m000000)... Thank you Evil Genius!